# How to programmatically obtain the mobile number from the current device?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, telephonymanager, android-intentservice

I want to obtain mobile number from device for registration page.
I used **TelephonyManager** but its not working in all devices and I also used **GoogleApiClient with HintRequest** in this service open dialogbox to select mobile number but its looking weird, so please suggest me a better option which is supported all android devices

Comment: There is no way which is supported in all Android devices.

Comment: Please don't Write with Random Upper case Letters because It's Harder to Read. That's not how you write English.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, thanks

Comment: This question has been asked about a hundred times. I've closed this as duplicate. Please see the linked question and read the answers and comments. Generally speaking, the answer is: "you cannot reliably get the number". Calling `TelefonyManager.getLine1Number()` will return the phone number which is written on the SIM card. This may be the user's number, it may be null and it is possible that the user has changed his number and this is his old number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to ask user to manually type his own phone number. Telephony permission looks dangerous and you can face issues with releasing to google play store.

Typically, you may also need to [intercept incoming sms messages](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/09/intercept-incoming-sms-android.html)